# Issue with integration by substitution

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing for finals, and I'm having issues with a particular question. I am a freshman taking calculus 1, and I am not a math major.
The question I am having difficulty with says to evaluate the indefinite integral of $$\int\frac{xdx}{{(x^2+2)^{1/2}}}$$
I replaced $$x^2+2$$ with $u$, which gave me a $\frac{du}{dx}$ of $2x$. Therefore, $\frac{du}{2}=xdx$.
this then gives me $$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u^{1/2}}$$
I then use the definition of integration to get $$\frac{1}{2}\ln(u^{1/2})$$
Once I substitute the original $$\frac{1}{2}\ln((x^2+2)^{1/2})$$
The program I am using says that this answer is wrong, but I can't find the error in my work. Can you please point it out, or confirm the answer? Thanks

Comment: There are a few errors above. You didn't account for the $x$ factor in $\frac{du}{2}=x dx$... Also you have integrated $u^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ w.r.t. $u$ incorrectly. Also the substitution you chose will not work anyways.

Comment: If you have done hyperbolic functions. it is very quick with $x=\sqrt{2}\sinh t$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question isn't at the level of hyperbolic functions, if he tried to do a u-substitution. Just saying...

Comment: If you haven't learned trig substitution or the hypberbolic stuff, I'm curious if you typed the integral correctly? Did you mean to type $\int \frac{x}{(x^2+2)^\frac{1}{2}} dx$ ? Then getting to $\frac{1}{2} \int u^\frac{-1}{2} du$ was correct. And you just use the power rule for integration. That is $ \int u^n du=\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} +C, n \neq -1$

Comment: That is what I typed, someone else edited it for me, and I don't have enough reputation to change it back

Comment: @danielfurhang then just your integration part is incorrect. Do you understand how to correct it now?

Comment: I thought that the integral of 1/u is ln(u), not ln((u^2)/2). Do you just take the natural log of the denominator, or do you take the natural log of the integral of the denominator?

Comment: You do know $\frac{1}{u^\frac{1}{2}}$ is $u^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ right? Your answer will not have natural log function in it...If you had $\int \frac{ f'(x)}{f(x)} dx=\ln|f(x)|+C$ but you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \neq \ln(\sqrt{x})$.

In fact, $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \int x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2} + 1}}{-\frac{1}{2} + 1} = \frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2\sqrt{x}$$

Using your same substition, let $u = x^2 + 2$. Then $du = 2xdx$ so $dx = \frac{du}{2x}$. We have
$$\int \frac{1}{2xu^\frac{1}{2}}du$$

Can you see why this might be a problem? Even if we rearrange $u = x^2 + 2$, we get $x = \pm\sqrt{u-2}$, which doesn't really help us either. I suggest a different approach.

I prefer to look at it like
$$\int \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2}}dx$$

Then it's easier to see how this might be done with trigonometric substitution. Let $u = \tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})$. Then $x=\sqrt{2}\tan(u)$ and $dx = \sqrt{2}\sec^2(u)du$. So our integral is now
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{2}\int \displaystyle \frac{\sec^2(u)}{\sqrt{2\tan^2(u) + 2}}du
&= \sqrt{2}\int \displaystyle \frac{\sec^2(u)}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\tan^2(u) + 1}}du \\
&= \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\int \displaystyle \frac{\sec^2(u)}{\sqrt{\sec^2(u)}}du \\
&= \int \displaystyle \frac{\sec^2(u)}{\sec(u)}du \\
&= \int \displaystyle \sec(u)du \\
&= \ln(\tan(u) + \sec(u))\\
&= \ln\left(\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) + \sec\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right) \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2} + 1}\right) + C
\end{align*}

I don't think I remember doing trigonometric substitution in Calculus 1, so this probably isn't the most elegant solution, but I think it works.

Comment: I haven't yet learned trigonometric substitution, so this doesn't really make sense to me. However, I tried putting in the answer you gave me just to satisfy curiosity, and the program wouldn't accept it.

Comment: This is much simpler with hyperbolic functions. Have you learned them?

Comment: I did not learn them

Comment: I suggest you talk to your professor about this one, then. Perhaps I'm missing a simple trick that can do this with u-substitution. Otherwise it makes no sense to assign this to a Calculus 1 course.

Answer (score 0):

This integral requires the trigonometric substitution $x= \sqrt(2) * \tan(\theta)$.

The differential $dx = \sqrt(2) \sec^2(\theta)$